# Error when building VS2008 solution with TFS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm getting following error when building my VS2008 Solution with TFS2010.

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\AssemblyInfoTask\Microsoft.VersionNumber.Targets" was not found.
Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Can someone help me with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like MSBuild could not find AssemblyInfoTask\Microsoft.VersionNumber.Targets, one possible problem is that the build service does not do a recursive search for the custom tasks to download them. See if your problem is similar to this one:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/dfefb86a-a969-4545-9f0d-7e764fd49861

Aaron Hallberg describes how to configure the build service to search for the custom tasks recursively here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2008/02/12/modifying-the-configurationfolderpath-recursiontype-in-team-build-2008.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: The solution provided by Aaron is not working for me. The additonal key mentioned (<add key="ConfigurationFolderRecursionType" value="Full" />) is already inlcuded in TfsBuildService.exe.config file. Any other ideas?

Comment: I fianlly solved the problem. The AssemblyInfoTask folder was missing on the new buildserver. So I just copied it from the old one. Works fine for me now

Comment: Yeah, if you checkin the AssemblyInfoTask folder to version control under the configuration path of the TfsBuild.proj, it should be picked up to the any build machine you create.